# How to fix nodejs Bcrypt Password same but response false

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

**how to fix?, password is 123456 is same but is not working to compare.**

I have checked that they are all correct.

```
//const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const auth_signin_email = async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    if (!email || !password) {
        res.status(400)
        res.json({message: 'Email invaild'})
    };
    //sequelize mysql
    oldData = await auth.findOne({
        where: {email: email}
    })
    // check oldData == null
    if (oldData == null) {
        res.json({messages: 'Not found Email, Please Try again'})
    };
    /*password is 123456*/
    bcrypt.compare(password, oldData.password, function (err, isLogged) {
        //this False
        if (isLogged) {
            const token = jwt.sign({data: oldData}, secret, {expiresIn: '12h',
            algorithm:'PS384'});
            res.json({token: token})
        } else {
            res.status(400)
            res.json({message: 'Wrong Email or Password'})
        }
    })
}
```

password = 123456 
oldData.password = hash of 123456

```
bcrypt.compare(password, oldData.password, function (err, isLogged) {
        //this False
        if (isLogged) {
            const token = jwt.sign({data: oldData}, secret, {expiresIn: '12h',
            algorithm:'PS384'});
            res.json({token: token})
        } else {
            res.status(400)
            res.json({message: 'Wrong Email or Password'})
        }
})
```

Comment: Are types of those string ? You should check the types with typeof method.

Answer (score 1):

it might be because your `oldData.password` is a hashed string `'123456'` and the value you are using in compare is a number `123456` which results in `isLogged` to be `false`.

You may try `password.toString()` in the bcrypt.compare function